# Symfony custom task doesn't work on hosting

Tags: php, symfony1, cron, task

I created a custom task which works fine on my development machine, but when i uploaded it to the server i get the message bellow.

> Task "project:update-countries" is not
>   defined.

Are there any other settings to make so it can run?

Thank you,
Radu.

Comment: Did you clear your cache? Are you in the correct folder?

Comment: @Maerlyn - yes, i cleared the cache

Comment: @zanlok - an example of how i ask for the task on my machine is: php /path_to_project/symfony project:update-countries; and on my live machine: php /home/mydomain/pathtoproject/symfony project:update-countries

Comment: Try changing your cwd to the project's directory, and do `./symfony project:update-countries`.

Comment: I cannot change path. I call the task through a cron task.

Comment: Yes, you can. I have cronjobs like `*/15 * * * * cd /path/to/project; time php symfony project:update-countries`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a bunch! Post it as answer and i will accept it as best answer. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your current working directory to the project's root, and run the command there. In your crontab, it should look like this:

```
*/15 * * * * cd /path/to/project; time php symfony project:update-countries
```

Comment: Thanks Maerlyn. I might be doing something wrong here but I tried using cd /home3/myspace/public_html/prasad/myapp/code; /ramdisk/bin/php5 symfony myapp:job --job-type="job" AND ALSO cd /home3/myspace/public_html/prasad/myapp/code && /ramdisk/bin/php5 /home3/myspace/public_html/prasad/myapp/code/symfony myapp:job --job-type="job" Can you pl help?

Comment: the other task in the same folder and namespace works fine via the command you suggested.

Comment: thanks Maerlyn. The task was recognized on Local but not on the hosting. I re-created the task using the generate:task command and a different namespace:name, it then worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the filename of the uploaded task looks like this:

```
namespace + task name + "Task.class.php"

Ex: projectUpdateCountriesTask.class.php
```

Different names results to be not accepted by Symfony so the task will not appear in the internal list of tasks even if in the file was specified the desired namespace and filename.